# MP3 file recognition, tagging, renaming

Tags: mp3, rename, tags

I have a bunch of MP3s with nonsensical/incorrect file names and only a few tags.

Is there software out there that will read each file, find out the right tags, replace them and use the tags to make a good filename?

Comment: Any software that can read tag info will work as long as the info is in the tag. I like to use [TagScanner](http://www.xdlab.ru/en/)

Answer (score 5):

- [Mp3tag](http://www.mp3tag.de/en/index.html) supports both batch tag editing, as well as renaming files from tags. It also supports importing tags from online databases like Amazon, discogs, freedb, MusicBrainz etc.
- If your files are not even tagged properly in the first place, I highly recommend  [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Picard), which "supports the majority of audio file formats, is capable of using audio fingerprints [for song identification], performing CD lookups and disc ID submissions" and so on.

If you don't use Windows, you should edit your question and mention your OS.

Comment: +1 was going to mention both Mp3tag and Picard myself

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use/be cursed with iTunes as I am, I have used TuneUp previously and had good luck with it. (I am not affiliated in any way with them)

http://www.tuneupmedia.com/